# Are non-orientable manifolds necessarily compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, compact-manifolds, non-orientable-surfaces

If not, what is an example of a non-compact, [open](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OpenManifold.html) manifold that is non-orientable? So if non-orientability $\Rightarrow$ compactness, is there a theorem and what is the proof?

Answer (score 5):

A Möbius strip without boundary is not compact.

Comment: True. I think was also asking for, assuming one exists, is an example of a non-orientable manifold that is not *totally bounded*.

Comment: @MrX: I'm not sure what that means for a general topological manifold. How about gluing an infinitely long boundaryless ribbon to your Möbius strip at right angles?